# Why split and strip gives different output in python?

Tags: python, string, split, strip

I was trying to extract the state name from the string `'Rhode Island[edit]'`.

When I tried `.split('[[]').str[0]`, I was given the correct result 'Rhode Island'.
However, when I tried `.rstrip('[edit]')`, I was given the wrong result 'Rhode Islan'.

I got confused why the character 'd' before the left bracket was also removed when I used rstrip function.

Comment: The parameter to `rstrip()` is "*a string specifying the set of characters to be removed.*".  Read the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rstrip#str.rstrip

Comment: `'Rhode Island[edit]'.split('[[]').str[0]` is going to produce `AttributeError`; please verify that part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`S.rstrip([chars])` -> string or unicode

Return a copy of the string S with trailing whitespace removed.
If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
If chars is unicode, S will be converted to unicode before stripping

in your case the chars = ['[','e','d','i','t',']']
which contains 'd' there fore trailing string that formed by given chars is `d[edit]`

try regular expression

```
import re
re.compile(r'\[edit\]$').sub('','Rhode Island[edit]')
```

Comment: Using `re` is the best approach since it reveals the intent.

Answer (score 3):

`rstrip` doesn't do what you want, it removes all characters specified from the end of the string, so it removed '[', 'e', 'd', 'i', 't', and ']'. What you want is to split on '[' then take the first element: `'Rhode Island[edit]'.split('[')[0]`